# How to select the containing li with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
 <li><span class="close">&times;</span> <%= item %></li>
```

When the user clicks the close icon, I want to hide the `<li>`. How can I do that?

Comment: FIrst you can read jquery api site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you "select" a span, but lets assume you do it with a click.

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
});
```

you'd then get the closest LI element with [`closest();`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)